# MCR: segmentation violation detected on Linux x64 machine

Tags: matlab

we have just intalled MCR for a linux x64 machine, and we are getting the error below when trying to run our algorithm. No problem running that algorithm in other machine we are using.

Any help?

```
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
         Segmentation violation detected at Tue May 26 10:27:27 2015
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Configuration:
    Crash Decoding     : Disabled
    Current Visual     : 0x21 (class 4, depth 24)
    Default Encoding   : UTF-8
    GNU C Library      : 2.21 stable
    MATLAB Architecture: glnxa64
    MATLAB Root        : /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81
    MATLAB Version     : 8.1.0.604 (R2013a)
    Operating System   : Linux 3.19.0-15-generic #15-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 16 23:32:37 UTC 2015 x86_64
    Processor ID       : x86 Family 6 Model 42 Stepping 7, GenuineIntel
    Virtual Machine    : Java 1.6.0_17-b04 with Sun Microsystems Inc. Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
    Window System      : The X.Org Foundation (11701000), display :0

  Fault Count: 1


  Abnormal termination:
  Segmentation violation

  Register State (from fault):
    RAX = 0000000000000000  RBX = 00007f257d226160
    RCX = 0000000000000000  RDX = 0000000000000003
    RSP = 00007f25f720fff0  RBP = 00007f25f7210110
    RSI = 0000000000000000  RDI = 00007f257d225350

     R8 = 0000000000000018   R9 = 0000000000000000
    R10 = 00007f257d225000  R11 = 00007f257d226478
    R12 = 00007f257d490fa0  R13 = 0000000000000006
    R14 = 00007f257d225758  R15 = 00007f25f2400580

    RIP = 00007f260e9158ba  EFL = 0000000000010206

     CS = 0033   FS = 0000   GS = 0000

  Stack Trace (from fault):
  [  0] 0x00007f260e9158ba                        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2+00051386
  [  1] 0x00007f260e91e4b1                        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2+00087217
  [  2] 0x00007f260e919464                        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2+00066660
  [  3] 0x00007f260e91d9a3                        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2+00084387
  [  4] 0x00007f260d28afc9                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2+00004041
  [  5] 0x00007f260e919464                        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2+00066660
  [  6] 0x00007f260d28b62d                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2+00005677
  [  7] 0x00007f260d28b061                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2+00004193 dlopen+00000049
  [  8] 0x00007f26098d0ce1 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81//bin/glnxa64/libut.so+00281825
  [  9] 0x00007f2602060354 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00328532
  [ 10] 0x00007f260205487d /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00280701 _ZN13Mlm_MATLAB_fn8try_loadEv+00000045
  [ 11] 0x00007f260204b95e /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00244062 _ZN13Mfh_MATLAB_fn11dispatch_fhEiPP11mxArray_tagiS2_+00000078
  [ 12] 0x00007f25ffe6d11c /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos.so+02208028
  [ 13] 0x00007f260208a58c /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00501132
  [ 14] 0x00007f260205fa6a /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00326250
  [ 15] 0x00007f260204baf8 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00244472 _ZN13Mfh_MATLAB_fn11dispatch_fhEiPP11mxArray_tagiS2_+00000488
  [ 16] 0x00007f26010f3778 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+02107256
  [ 17] 0x00007f26010f31f9 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+02105849
  [ 18] 0x00007f2601051acc /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+01444556 inCallFcnWithTrap+00000092
  [ 19] 0x00007f25fc21cbda /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libuij.so+00125914
  [ 20] 0x00007f25fc219039 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libuij.so+00110649
  [ 21] 0x00007f25fc219268 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libuij.so+00111208
  [ 22] 0x00007f25fc2193d9 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libuij.so+00111577
  [ 23] 0x00007f25fc236977 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libuij.so+00231799
  [ 24] 0x00007f25fc237f8d /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libuij.so+00237453
  [ 25] 0x00007f25fc238024 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libuij.so+00237604 _Z16UIJ_SetJavaFrameP10WinRec_tagPvb+00000020
  [ 26] 0x00007f25fed65a05 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwhg.so+05204485
  [ 27] 0x00007f25fed7351b /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwhg.so+05260571 UIJ_CreatePeerWindow+00000443
  [ 28] 0x00007f25fdd1c848 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwuix.so+00493640 _Z20create_figure_windowP10WinRec_tag+00000424
  [ 29] 0x00007f25fedbc492 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwhg.so+05559442
  [ 30] 0x00007f25fedbd5ff /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwhg.so+05563903
  [ 31] 0x00007f25fee61537 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwhg.so+06235447
  [ 32] 0x00007f25ffa04e0d /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwudd.so+00728589
  [ 33] 0x00007f25ffa00e55 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwudd.so+00712277 _ZN11UDInterface32notifyChildAddedAndParentChangedEPS_+00000213
  [ 34] 0x00007f25ffa01178 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwudd.so+00713080 _ZN11UDInterface8addRightEPS_+00000328
  [ 35] 0x00007f25ffa014b8 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwudd.so+00713912 _ZN11UDInterface13addFirstBelowEPS_+00000072
  [ 36] 0x00007f25fee3ba2f /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwhg.so+06081071
  [ 37] 0x00007f25fee62126 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwhg.so+06238502
  [ 38] 0x00007f25ff9fe8f9 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwudd.so+00702713 _ZN11UDInterface4setEEP16UDDatabaseClientP10UDPropInfoPvP13UDErrorStatus+00001065
  [ 39] 0x00007f25fee6053c /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwhg.so+06231356
  [ 40] 0x00007f25fee3939b /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwhg.so+06071195
  [ 41] 0x00007f25fee54741 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwhg.so+06182721
  [ 42] 0x00007f25fee4437b /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwhg.so+06116219
  [ 43] 0x00007f25fee44b46 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwhg.so+06118214
  [ 44] 0x00007f25fed736d3 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwhg.so+05261011 hgFigure+00000243
  [ 45] 0x00007f25c66b7188 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwhgbuiltins.so+00569736
  [ 46] 0x00007f25c668f43a /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwhgbuiltins.so+00406586
  [ 47] 0x00007f25c668f529 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwhgbuiltins.so+00406825
  [ 48] 0x00007f260205fa6a /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00326250
  [ 49] 0x00007f260204baf8 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00244472 _ZN13Mfh_MATLAB_fn11dispatch_fhEiPP11mxArray_tagiS2_+00000488
  [ 50] 0x00007f2601115256 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+02245206
  [ 51] 0x00007f26010c5a86 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+01919622
  [ 52] 0x00007f26010ca374 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+01938292
  [ 53] 0x00007f26010c6993 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+01923475
  [ 54] 0x00007f26010c7797 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+01927063
  [ 55] 0x00007f2601132e50 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+02367056
  [ 56] 0x00007f26020996b2 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00562866 _ZN8Mfh_file11dispatch_fhEiPP11mxArray_tagiS2_+00000594
  [ 57] 0x00007f2601301bf6 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+04262902
  [ 58] 0x00007f260130237a /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+04264826
  [ 59] 0x00007f2601302eea /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+04267754
  [ 60] 0x00007f2601165bbd /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+02575293
  [ 61] 0x00007f2601191412 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+02753554
  [ 62] 0x00007f260119153f /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+02753855
  [ 63] 0x00007f26012ae500 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+03921152
  [ 64] 0x00007f26010ca8ac /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+01939628
  [ 65] 0x00007f26010c6993 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+01923475
  [ 66] 0x00007f26010c7797 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+01927063
  [ 67] 0x00007f2601132e50 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+02367056
  [ 68] 0x00007f26020996b2 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00562866 _ZN8Mfh_file11dispatch_fhEiPP11mxArray_tagiS2_+00000594
  [ 69] 0x00007f2601301bf6 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+04262902
  [ 70] 0x00007f260130237a /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+04264826
  [ 71] 0x00007f2601302eea /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+04267754
  [ 72] 0x00007f2601165bbd /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+02575293
  [ 73] 0x00007f2601191412 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+02753554
  [ 74] 0x00007f260119153f /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+02753855
  [ 75] 0x00007f26012ae500 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+03921152
  [ 76] 0x00007f26010ca8ac /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+01939628
  [ 77] 0x00007f26010c6993 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+01923475
  [ 78] 0x00007f26010c7797 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+01927063
  [ 79] 0x00007f2601132e50 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+02367056
  [ 80] 0x00007f26020996b2 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00562866 _ZN8Mfh_file11dispatch_fhEiPP11mxArray_tagiS2_+00000594
  [ 81] 0x00007f26010f3778 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+02107256
  [ 82] 0x00007f26010f31f9 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+02105849
  [ 83] 0x00007f2601051acc /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+01444556 inCallFcnWithTrap+00000092
  [ 84] 0x00007f26010b80fb /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+01863931
  [ 85] 0x00007f2601050998 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+01440152 _Z28inCallFcnWithTrapInDesiredWSiPP11mxArray_tagiS1_PKcbP15inWorkSpace_tag+00000104
  [ 86] 0x00007f2601ab99a9 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwiqm.so+02931113 _ZN3iqm15BaseFEvalPlugin7executeEP15inWorkSpace_tagRN5boost10shared_ptrIN14cmddistributor17IIPCompletedEventEEE+00000457
  [ 87] 0x00007f26028376a9 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00390825
  [ 88] 0x00007f2601a914fa /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwiqm.so+02766074
  [ 89] 0x00007f2601a804ad /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwiqm.so+02696365
  [ 90] 0x00007f25fdd195c6 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwuix.so+00480710
  [ 91] 0x00007f25fdd26df2 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwuix.so+00536050
  [ 92] 0x00007f260cc56862 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81//bin/glnxa64/libmwservices.so+01845346
  [ 93] 0x00007f260cc5750f /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81//bin/glnxa64/libmwservices.so+01848591 _Z25svWS_ProcessPendingEventsiib+00001615
  [ 94] 0x00007f26028255ef /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00316911
  [ 95] 0x00007f2602825f5c /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00319324
  [ 96] 0x00007f260281f592 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00292242
  [ 97] 0x00007f260d85f6aa              /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0+00030378
  [ 98] 0x00007f260d594eed                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+01076973 clone+00000109


  If this problem is reproducible, please submit a Service Request via:
      http://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/

  A technical support engineer might contact you with further information.
```

Comment: Maybe you should do exactly what the error message suggests: contact MathWorks to get a technical support engineer's feedback/advice.

Comment: I guess you should send this to the MATLAB support

Answer (score 1):

NO, you don't need to run matlab a as root user. After installing Matlab, install matlab-support package,

```
 sudo apt-get purge matlab-support
```

, where you can configure who should able to the Matlab and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You must run MATLAB as root user